# Get random Wikipedia extract with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wikipedia-api

I'm trying to get the extract of a random Wikipedia page using Ajax. I've got as far as getting the data, but I'm having trouble outputting it.

Here's my code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://simple.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=random&grnnamespace=0&prop=extracts&exsentences=10&format=json&callback=?",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            var text = data.parse;
            document.getElementById('div_text').innerHTML = text;
        },
        error: function (errorMessage) {
        }
    });
```

The console logs the data fine, but the output in the browser is simply `undefined`.

Clearly, the problem is this line:

```
var text = data.parse;
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is not in `data.parse` but in `data.query.pages` and in there the first object.

So change you success method to

```
success: function (data) {
        var pages = data.query.pages;
        var text = pages[ Object.keys(pages)[0] ].extract;
        document.getElementById('div_text').innerHTML = text;
    }
```